# ngOnChanges not fired in native or in mobile web. Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic4

I have a component with this template:

```
 <app-graph-grouped-vertical
      [results]="graphRecords"
      [series]="graphPredictions"
      [seriesColors]="predictionColors"
      [xAxis]="xAxis"
></app-graph-grouped-vertical>
```

And inside **GraphGroupedVerticalComponent**, I got this:

```
export class GraphGroupedVerticalComponent extends GraphBaseComponent<GroupedResultDto>
  implements OnChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy, DoCheck {
...
 @Input() results!: GroupedResultDto[]

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){console.log('Triggered')}
...

}
```

So, when I get into the browser from the computer and the property `graphRecords` in the parent component changes everything works well, and the `ngOnChanges` in the child gets triggered. The thing is, when I use the app from a mobile browser or from the compiled native app, it won't trigger. For it to trigger, after `records` has changed I have to press something in the screen, anything (not a blank space, but an interactive element. It doesn't have to be related to the component or that property).

It happens in physical phones **and** in the emulator, Android and iOS.

I have even tried using `ngDoCheck`, but it doesn't trigger either. I'm kind of desperate, does anyone know what could be happening?

I'm using Ionic 4 and Angular 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it took me a while to figure out what was happening. It turns out that the operation of assigning the new value to `records` was happening outside `ngZone`. To anyone unfamiliar with this, zones are like a closed environment in which processes are run, and `ngZone` is where Angular runs asynchronous operations, and will change the UI accordingly.

This also goes the other way. If something is executed *outside* `ngZone`, Angular's ChangeDetection won't listen to it, and our UI won't change. Fortunately, you can force something to run inside `ngZone` by using `ngZone.run()`. And you can also run heavy operations outside of it so Angular does not refresh the UI unnecessarily, thus optimizing your app.

However, I still don't know why this specific operation was involuntarily executing outside `ngZone`...